# How to create external table using dbt from Google Sheet to BigQuery?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, dbt

I want to create external table in BigQuery and the data source is from Google Sheet. Is it possible to do it using dbt? In the `yml` file, where should I put the URI?
The main problem is, I don’t have the access to create it directly in BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle a Google Sheet as a source is by creating a new table out of it in BigQuery via [Connected Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets).
Then, you create a new `source` in dbt that relies on that table, and start building your downstream models from there.

As far as I know, you cannot create a source directly from dbt, unless it is a `seed` file, which I woul not recommend unless it is a rather static file (e.g. country names and ISO codes, which is not prone to change over time).

Comment: thanks. it answers my question really well. ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation where the data source is from Google Sheet.

The end user updates the Google sheet on a periodical basic and we replicate it using Fivetran to our Snowflake datastore.

DBT can then pick up the data seamlessly.

Comment: but in my case, i couldn’t replicate it.